# TS2322 : '(errors: ValidationError[]) => Error' is not assignable to type '(errors: ValidationError[]) => any', why Error is not assignable to any

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

```
lib/admin/server/index.ts:87:5 - error TS2322: Type '(errors: ValidationError[]) => Error' is not assignable to type '(errors: ValidationError[]) => any'.
  Types of parameters 'errors' and 'errors' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/xxxxxx/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/common/interfaces/external/validation-error.interface").ValidationError[]' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/xxxxx/backend/node_modules/class-validator/types/validation/ValidationError").ValidationError[]'.

87     exceptionFactory(errors: ValidationError[]): Error {
```

I updated **nestjs** from 7.0 to 7.6 and I got these errors, I'm a bit familiar with TS but cant get what the 'Error' is saying that Error is not assignable to 'any'.

And it would be helpful if someone can provide the Link to ChangeLog of Nest.js since I haven't been able to find it

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are importing your `validationError[]` from the nestjs interface.

`Error` should be a subset of `any`, since any is just letting typescript knowing that you opt out of type checking.

Comment: The Error Resolved when imported from Nest's interface rather than from Class-validator but nest in turn uses class-validators interface itself so why does it throw an error